# How to find a java script or jquery to run images in slide show like rss feed

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider

I was searching for a code that can let me do a cycling and moving images like this website http://www.monsacpublicitaire.com/ "see the slider under the word REFERENCE in french" where the logos moving from right to left like rss feed.

I hope anyone can help.

Thank you

Comment: You could use the awesome MARQUEE tag. More seriously, this question doesn't fit with SO rules...

Comment: Sorry A. Wolff, what is SO roles, do I make any wrong way to question?

Comment: SO rules for stackoverflow.com rules. You cannot ask for recommending plugin or tool, to avoid spamming. But as no one came here to spam, that's ok i guess

Comment: Sorry any way, I am new here, don't know the roles, but thank you for the advice, and thank you for help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use bx slider try this link http://bxslider.com/
site you mentioned is using "simplyScroll js" you can also use same library 
http://logicbox.net/jquery/simplyscroll/

Comment: how will you do kind of infinite scrolling using this slider?

Comment: Thank you Akh for the fast reply, but this is the slider with right and left arrow, what I am looking for is moving small images side by side like rss feed and the moving will stop on mouse over

Comment: @A.Wolff we have property infiniteLoop, by setting this to true infinite scrolling can be achieved.

Comment: @Khalil check updated solution

Comment: @Akh but infinite scrolling has latency in bxslider. Anyway, looks like bringing gun at pillow fight, imho

Comment: Yes ..... Akh, Your updated answer with second link will work, Thank you very much :)

Comment: i give +1 for second link, seems exactly to be it ;)

Comment: Sorry Akh for not voting because I don't have enough reputation I cant give you any +, but thank you very much for your help

Comment: @Khalil i am here to help others and to get help if i needed but not for votes. cheers :)

Comment: Hi Akh, I am sorry to buther you again, but I am facing difficulty merging this script to my Magento theme, here is my link, http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/accueil.html, I need to apply that to the 2nd small slide show down the page, I applied all the css and script to the page, but it is still show me images with bullets under each other, if you could help me with that, thank you

Comment: @Khalil you directly added the simplyscroll.js in html code, dont do that add it as a reference and after that you can call $("#scroller").simplyScroll(); under document.ready.

Comment: Yes, it works, Thank you, you can see it here: http://www.cabas-durables.fr/magento/index.php/accueil.html, Thank you very much for your help